# How to use socket.io browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, browserify

How do I use socket.io with browserify?

When socket.io is installed in a node app, it creates this url path for ths socket.io script:

/socket.io/socket.io.js

But what would be the real path of that file (relative to the node_modules dir) which needs to be passed to browserify?

Is it e.g.

socket.io-client/socket.io.js

or maybe

socket.io/lib/client.js

In the documentation of socket.io-client it says "Socket.IO is compatible with browserify." But they don't say how.

Answer (score 3):

If you struggled to get it working with browserify as a window global use this code for the integration:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
window.io = io;
```

Comment: it worked thanks. is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minimal client:

```
// client.js
var socket = require('socket.io-client')();
socket.on('message', ...);
```

Which you can Browserify:

```
browserify client.js > bundle.js
```

Comment: To get this working, I needed to pass the URL and port, i.e. `var socket = require('socket.io-client')("http://localhost:8080");`.

Answer (score 0):

The path will be exactly the same since it's the server who serve the socket.io client library (and I guess you're not `browserify`ing the server, are you?).

But I use a more convenient solution: check this out.

```
io  =   require 'socket.io-client'

class Network

    constructor: (game, refresh_infos) ->

        @sock = io()
        #...

    pending: (name, cb) ->

        @name = name
        @sock.emit 'pending', name: name
        @sock.on 'new_game', (data) => cb data
```

Abrakadabra!

Comment: It's coffeescript, but I guess you'll have no hard time to translate it to JS.

Comment: "The path will be exactly the same since ..."

Sorry for my ignorance here, but exactly the same as _what_?

Comment: The same as if you weren't using browserify.

Comment: I don't think so. But maybe my question wasn't sufficiently specific. What I want to do is something like this (simplified example):

`app.get('/myscript.js', function( req, res) {

    var jsFiles = ['local/path/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/index.js', local/path/someother.js];

    var b = browserify(jsFiles).bundle();

    b.on('error', console.error);
    
    b.pipe(res);

});`

Sorry, this doesn't properly format the code.

Comment: Hu so you want to include directly and dynamically `socket.io-client` into your bundle? Why not just require it above your client code?

Answer (score 0):

Import client and then assign it to variable with:

```
var client = require('socket.io/lib/client');
```

You can then call `client`.